# NodeJS. Вывод списка роутеров приложения функцией

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, циклы

Всем доброго времени суток.

Пишу небольшое MVC приложение на `NodeJS` и немного застрял с созданием роутера, а точнее с одной из функций данного класса.

Ближе к делу. Я хочу, чтобы моё приложение "сканировало" папку 'Modules' в которой будут содержатся различные модули приложения, к примеру модуль админ-панели, либо же сам фронтенд, который доступен пользователю.

На данный момент моя папка 'Modules' выглядит так:

`Modules/Frontend
        Controller/...
        Model/...
        View/...
        router.json
Modules/Backend
        Controller/...
        Model/...
        View/...
        router.json`

Что мне необходимо реализовать?

Для начала я создал функцию, которая сканирует папку модулей и получает роутер каждой из папок, но проблема в следующем, функция записывает пути к каждому пути роутера, но когда возвращает мне результат стирает массив и мне приходит пустой массив. Это происходит из-за того, что в начале функции определен массив `let list = []` - то есть пустой массив, без этого функция попросту не работает.

Вот весь код самой функции:

```
function Search(startPath){
        // Название файла роутера
        let filter = 'route.json';
        let list = [];

        // Проверка, если имя папки не задано, то присваиваем ей нужное имя
        if(startPath === undefined)
            startPath = 'Modules';

        // console.log(`Проверка директории: ${startPath}, файл не найден.`);

        // Проверка на ошибку, есть ли такая директория.
        if (!fs.existsSync(startPath)){
            console.log("Нет такой директории: ",startPath);
            return;
        }

        // Цикл поиска файла
        let files = fs.readdirSync(startPath);
        for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            let filename=path.join(startPath,files[i]);
            let stat = fs.lstatSync(filename);
            // Если файл не найден, то запускаем цикл повторно
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                this.Search(filename,filter);
            }
            // Если файл найден, кладем его в массив.
            else if (filename.indexOf(filter)>=0) {
                list = [filename];

            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

На выходе мне нужно получить пути ко всем роутерам, либо "склеить" все файлы роутеров в один и отдать массив на выходе.

Как подобное можно реализовать?

Comment: `list = [filename];` -> `list.push(filename);` ;;; `this.Search(filename,filter)` -> `list.push(...this.Search(filename,filter))`

Comment: `return;` -> `return [];`

Comment: @Grundy Большое спасибо, изменил то, что вы сказали и всё заработало корректно! :)